# Inverse square law-type integral over two line segments

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, 3d, multiple-integral

This is a question I ended up with while trying to make a program that would find an (at least locally-) minimal-energy configuration for a piecewise linear 1-dimensional object in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in relation to a practical knot theory type of question. If it helps at all for the purposes of context or intuition, the setup described here is essentially asking for the electrostatic force between two one-dimensional nonconducting rods, as seen from one endpoint of one of the rods, with uniform charge distribution.

Let $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, $(X_0, Y_0, Z_0)$, $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$, and $(X_1, Y_1, Z_1)$ be four elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$, with the standard Euclidean norm $\lVert (x, y, z) \rVert = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$. What is
$$\int_{0}^{1} \!\! \int_{0}^{1} \!\! \frac{\displaystyle \big( (x_0, y_0, z_0) + (X_0 - x_0, Y_0 - y_0, Z_0 - z_0) u \big) - \big( (x_1, y_1, z_1) + (X_1 - x_1, Y_1 - y_1, Z_1 - z_1) v \big)}{\displaystyle {\left\lVert \big( (x_0, y_0, z_0) + (X_0 - x_0, Y_0 - y_0, Z_0 - z_0) u \big) - \big( (x_1, y_1, z_1) + (X_1 - x_1, Y_1 - y_1, Z_1 - z_1) v \big) \right\rVert}^3} \ \mathrm{d} v \ u \ \mathrm{d} u?$$

I'm pretty sure this should have a closed-form solution, but after a bunch of WolframAlpha, find-and-replace, and failing to apply manual partial integration correctly, I've only gotten rid of one of the integrations and the remaining one looks so messy I reckon I must have missed some important simplification somewhere, although it numerically comes out the same as the original double integral so I doubt I made a mistake in manipulation. With $a_0 = X_0 - x_0$, $b_0 = Y_0 - y_0$, $c_0 = Z_0 - z_0$, $a_1 = X_1 - x_1$, $b_1 = Y_1 - y_1$, and $c_1 = Z_1 - z_1$, a screenshot from Desmos of the result I have obtained so far is below.

**EDIT:** I realized that the form of the integral that I was solving in the screenshot below, as well as the one I originally asked about, simply had a $\mathrm{d} u$ term as opposed to the $u\ \mathrm{d} u$ I actually meant to be investigating, so it (as per the physical intuition) was measuring the total force over the entire line from $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ to $(X_0, Y_0, Z_0)$ instead of just the force percieved by $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$. Just imagine it ends in $u\ \mathrm{d} u$ instead of just $du$. However, if the $\mathrm{d} u$ form is substantially easier to solve, that would be acceptable as well; ideally I would be able to test both forms, but $u\ \mathrm{d} u$ is I believe more relevant to the physical intuition.

[image: single-integral form]

**UPDATE**: After some messing around I have managed to determine that the integral in question here, for both the $\mathrm{d} u$ and $u\ \mathrm{d} u$ versions, is invariant under applying an isometric transformation to the values $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, $(X_0, Y_0, Z_0)$, $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$, and $(X_1, Y_1, Z_1)$ and then applying the inverse map to the result of the integral, which allows me to assume WLOG that all of $x_0$, $y_0$, $z_0$, $Y_0$, and $Z_0$ are all zero, which turns the above integral into
[image: single-integral form after isometric transformation]
after a $u$- (or I guess more properly a $v$- in this case) substitution of $v = X_0 u$, of course replacing the $\mathrm{d} v$ by $\frac{v}{X_0}\ \mathrm{d} v$ for the $u\ \mathrm{d} u$ form. This is a bit better, I think, but I doubt it actually helps much if at all toward getting a solution.

Comment: If you are already in the middle of programming why not integrate that thing numerically?

Comment: @Kurt G. That was my first thought as well, actually! The problem boils down to the fact that the way I am using this integral is as a summand in the equation for the second derivative of the position of each point, of which there could easily be 1000 or more, each with a line to the next point, so I'd have to do around a million numerical integrations (one for each pair of lines) every time I wanted to evaluate the function for my numerical ODE setup. I'm using numpy, so an array-based closed-form solution would not only be more accurate but almost certainly much faster

Comment: If speed is an issue try a Gaussian quadrature on the integral. It needs the integrand to be  smooth and I believe it is but you will  know better. This will be much faster then a standard numerical integrator. After decades of programming I am telling you that searching for closed form solutions for everything is not worth it.

Comment: @Kurt G. Thank you so much for that tip; I legitimately forgot about quadrature. I'm going to leave the question open nonetheless since I still believe a closed-form solution would be a little faster and definitely more mathematically appealing.

Comment: As a programming sidenote, for the quadrature, should I give it the single-integral form from my Desmos screenshot or the double-integral form from the question statement itself?

Comment: during development you should try both. how else do you want to avoid bugs in your code? having said that: that single integral looks horrendous.